# Using libraries after importing them into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have added two libraries to my project and included the text needed into the build.grandle file. Is there anything else I need to do?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Realized that they have changed their package, everything working!